# Printing the i'th character of each i'th word instead of just one

Tags: java, loops

I am working on a simple program where the goal is to print the i'th character of each i'th word that the user inputs. I have the number of words set to 5 as an example, and so the user needs to enter 5 words. However, the program returns the i'th character of just one of the i'th words (I have "i" set to 2). How would I fix this so that it prints the i'th character for each i'th word, instead of just one of the i'th words?

Here is my code for reference:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Words {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int numWords = 5;
    
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] words = new String[numWords];
    System.out.print("Enter " + numWords + " words: ");
    
    for (int i = 0;i<numWords;i++) {
        String word = keyboard.next();
        words[i] = word;
    }
    
    keyboard.close();
    
    int iVal = 2;
    
    int length = words[iVal].length();
    
    if (iVal >= (length - 1)) {
        System.out.print(words[iVal].charAt(length-1));
    }
    
    else {
        System.out.print(words[iVal].charAt(iVal));
    }
    
}

}
```

This is the output I get as an example:

```
Enter 5 words: one two three four five
r
```

Comment: To do it more than once, you'd need a loop. Since you already have a loop, it seems you know about them, so why is this even in question?

Comment: @Andreas I guess I'm mainly asking about how to make that loop go through every i'th word so that I skip the unnecessary words and only print the characters from those that I need, in this case being every 2 words.

Comment: You need to actually write a loop around the code that does the printing.  It's outside the loop you've got (that's ok) so needs to be in a separate loop.  As it stands, you only process the 3rd word (the ival'th word, starting at , with ival=2).  This loop will increment some index through the values ival, 2*ival, 3*ival,....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop may be implemented similar to what has already been implemented:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < numWords; i++) {
    String word = words[i];

    if (i < word.length()) {
        System.out.println("char #" + i + " = " + word.charAt(i));
    } else {
        System.out.println("Word + " + word + " is too short to get char #" + i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This simply splits the string on spaces and the prints the `ith-1` character of the `ith` word (so the first word would be character at 0, the second word would be character at 1 and so forth).  If the word is too short, it is skipped.

```
String str = "A is for apple and E is for Encyclopedia";
int i = 0;
for (String s : str.split("\\s+")) {
    if (i < s.length()) {
        System.out.println(s + " --> " + s.charAt(i));
    }
    i++;
}
```

Prints

```
A --> A
is --> s
for --> r
apple --> l
Encyclopedia --> e
```